# PHP Mysqli Insert not working but only in one place

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code as part of my shopping basket. The Insert Orders query is working but I can not get the Insert Order_Info query to insert data. Can anyone help give me some guidance please?

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/functions.php");

if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
global $mysqli;
$accountnumber=$_REQUEST['accountnumber'];
$addressbook=$_REQUEST['addressid'];

$date=date('Y-m-d');
$result=$mysqli->query("insert into Orders  values('','$date','$findID','$addressbook','Pending')");
$orderid=mysql_insert_id();

$max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
$pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
$q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
$price=get_price($pid);
$sql("insert into Order_Info values ($orderid,$pid,$q,$price)");
} header( "refresh:0;url=my_orders.php" );
unset($_SESSION['cart']);    
die('');

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your sql statement, but you haven't run the query though. First query runs because you have your query
Add this: $mysqli->query($sql);

Comment: Thank you, how would this be inserted?

Comment: Under your $sql statement

Answer (score 0):

You haven't run the second query plus you need to use it like this
$orderid = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);